# Win 7 - Tomcat unable connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, windows-7

I moved our code (web programming) to Win 7 from Win XP.  All the thing were nearly the same,
Old System (It works for few years)
Win XP / Tomcat 5.5 /  MySQL 5.0 / MySQL Adminstrator & Query Brower / JDBC 5.0

New System
Win 7 / Tomcat 5.5 / **MySQL 5.5** / Workbench CE 5.2 / JDBC 5.0

Using Workbench to create user without password same as old one, but I got the below error,
Access denied for user 'jytsd'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I has checked many times about the user info, but found nothing.  Could anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't connect that way.  Use the type IV JDBC connector for MySQL.  Put it in the Tomcat 7 /lib directory and configure your data source and JNDI lookup like this:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks!  JDBC 5.0, I means Connector/J which should be Type IV.  I followed your suggestion, installing Tomcat 7, most update connector/J.  But, it didn't work.  Finally, I added password to the user, then I got the connection.  I'm not sure whether it's the key point.  Anyway, it works!  Thanks again!  Honson